# proxy external api into nuxtjs / vuejs devserver with axios

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

As an example I would like this axios call :

```
export default {
    async asyncData({ app }) {
        const nations = await app.$axios.$get('https://my-api.com/api/v1/test')
        console.log(nations)
    }
}
```

... to be accessible from :

```
app.$axios.$get('/test')
```

Meaning, I have a Nuxtjs app running locally, where my backend is hosted on another domain. So I would like to proxy this into my local environment. When I was running the same application in vue-cli, I had no issues, but I can't figure out how to configure this correctly in Nuxtjs.

I have tried alot of combinations, but I would like to share my current try (which also fails)

from nuxt.config.js:

```
// Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/bootstrap
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    //
    '@nuxtjs/proxy'
  ],
  proxy: {
    // Simple proxy
    '/api': { target: 'https://my-api.com', pathRewrite: {'^/api/': '/'}, changeOrigin: true }
  },

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    //proxy:true,
    baseURL: '/api/v1',
    debug: true
  }
```

Can anyone figure out, what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Have I misunderstood the question, or would setting a base url within axios not solve this problem?

Comment: I thought so too... but no :-/

Comment: I get a 404 no matter what I try :-( - and can’t even trace the request in network monitor...